# How to pass a string by refrence in Turbo C/C++

Tags: c++, string, function, reference

[I am using the following code

```
void fix_filename(char[], char[], int);

int  main(){
    int i;
    char k,l[100];

    cin >> i;
    fix_filename(l,"books",i);
    cout << "Stringis: ";
    puts(l);

    return 0;
}

void fix_filename(char k[] ,char pre[] ,int n){
    int i = 0, div, r = 0, pk;
    char temp, str[100];
    div = n;

    while(div!=0){
        r = div % 10;
        k[i] = 48+r;
        div=div / 10;
        i++;
    }

    k[i] = '\0';

    pk = strlen(k);

    for(i=0;i<pk/2;i++){
        temp = k[i];
        k[i] = k[pk-i-1];
        k[pk-i-1]=temp;
    }

    k = strcat(pre,k);
}
```

But my string is filled with junk values (string l[100]) .. how to make it be passed by refrence in turbo c/c++ ?

The reason i am using turbo c/c++ , is that it is assigment and i cant use any other compilers.

I expect the output of the string (l) to be books121 , where 121 is the input.

Comment: `C/C++` is not a language. Pick one. The idiomatic solutions will differ substantially in the two languages.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you would expect to receive in which variable?

Comment: c++/C any of these .. prefer c++  please

Comment: I don't see how that even compiles - `l` in `main` is an uninitialised `char`, but you need it to be an array.

Comment: Changed `char l` to `char l[100]` .. still no effect

Answer (score 1):

In C, Compiler interprets function declaration

```
void fix_filename( char []  ,char [] ,int );
```

as

```
void fix_filename( char *  ,char * ,int );
```

it means you need to pass pointer to `cahr` (`char *`) to your function. But you are passing `char l` your function.

```
fix_filename(l,"books",i);
```

Comment: Please see again , i passed a char array , `l[100]`

Comment: Do not try to make me fool. You have edited your question. Still `i` is not an array.

Comment: i Didnt meant that .. sorry if that offended you . I meant i tried it , You can see my comment @top and i never meant to make `i` an array .. i want it to be int only.

Answer (score 1):

```
void fix_filename(char k[] ,char pre[] ,int n )
```

In this function you want to recieve a `char[]` as the first argument and in `main()`, you are *passing a single character*?

I suggest you to learn you lecture more thoroghly and *use a good compiler.*

Comment: Longer variable names wouldn't hurt either.